# customised serialisation in Java

Tags: java, serialization, kryo

I am aware of Java Serialization and also have heard about `Custom Java serialization`. Personally, I haven't ever done any `custom serialization`, however a bit of custom serialization I am aware of that we need to provide `writeObject()` and `readObject()`.

I am not clear on the concepts, I read that there are external frameworks / libs which also does `custom serialization` e.g. `kryo`.

So how is this `custom serialization` achieved? Is it eventually done by `JVM` even if we use a some libs/framework.

If we use , for example `kryo` , is behind the scene work done by that framework (e.g., `kryo`), and if so, do that object that needs to be `Serializable` need to implement `Serializabe` interface?

Can anyone help understand this?

Comment: If you want to custom serialization, apart from Serializable interface, you can also leverage Externalizable interface which good and fast as compared to Serializable interface.

Comment: I am looking more from other framework e.g. Kryo, in that how do they do Serialization, if we don't use Java's in-built mechanism?